# Find Quarter to which a particular date belong for a Fiscal year

Tags: java

I am using java 1.7, How to find the quarter  to which  a particular date belong for a Fiscal year, which can start from 1st of any month (JAN-DEC) and also need the start date and end date of that Quarter.

i.e Suppose FY(1 April 2017 - 31 March 2018) then Date 26 June 2017 belong to Q1(Quarter 1) and quarter start date is 1 October 2017 and end date is 31 December 2017 ..etc

Comment: Isolate the month M from the date; if M is less than the starting month of the F/Y, add 12 to M; subtract F/Y start month from M to obtain month-of-FY MFY; divide MFY by 4 and add 1 to the quotient to obtain the quarter Q.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but In addition to the quarter , we need the start and end date of that particular quarter  as well.

Comment: Tip: search “Half-Open” and `YearMonth`. This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

java.time, the modern Java data and time API, gives you most of what you are asking for. Only it dies not know your financial year. The quarter you are asking for is one less that the quarter used in the ISO calendar system supported by java.time. So my trick is to subtract one quarter from your date and then query java.time about the quarter and year. That will give you the numbers you require.

In code, trying different dates:

```
    LocalDate[] exampleDates = {
            LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 1),
            LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JUNE, 30),
            LocalDate.of(2020, Month.AUGUST, 22),
            LocalDate.of(2020, Month.OCTOBER, 1),
            LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 31),
    };
    
    for (LocalDate date : exampleDates) {
        LocalDate syntheticQuarterDate = date.minus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS);
        
        // Get quarter number and year as int
        int quarter = syntheticQuarterDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);
        int year = syntheticQuarterDate.getYear();
        System.out.format("Quarter: %d; year: %d%n", quarter, year);
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> Quarter: 4; year: 2019
> Quarter: 1; year: 2020
> Quarter: 2; year: 2020
> Quarter: 3; year: 2020
> Quarter: 4; year: 2020
> ```

Suppose you wanted a string like `Q42019` rather than the numbers. In this case it’s best to use a formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter quarterFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("QQQuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now for each date do:

```
        // Print a string like "Q42019"
        String quarterString = syntheticQuarterDate.format(quarterFormatter);
        System.out.println(quarterString);
```

Output using the same dates as before:

> ```
> Q42019
> Q12020
> Q22020
> Q32020
> Q42020
> ```

### Question: Does that work with Java 7?

java.time works nicely on Java 7. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- My answer was also inspired by and written on the occasion of [this duplicate question: Java : How to get quarter year based on given date [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63404039/5772882)

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7, you could do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Dates are DD/MM/YYYY
    String date_string = "26/06/2017";

    String quarter_start_string = "01/04/2017";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date in_date = sdf.parse(date_string);
    Date qstart = sdf.parse(quarter_start_string);
    boolean found = false; 
    int quarter = 1;
    Calendar in_date_cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    in_date_cal.setTime(in_date);

    Calendar fq_start = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    fq_start.setTime(qstart);
    Calendar fq_end = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    fq_end.setTime(qstart);
    fq_end.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 3 );
    while (!found) { 
        if (in_date_cal.hashCode() >= fq_start.hashCode() && 
                in_date_cal.hashCode() <= fq_end.hashCode()) {
            break; 
        }
        fq_start.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 3 );
        fq_end.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 3 );
        quarter++; 
    }

    System.out.println("Quarter# is " + quarter);
    System.out.println("Quarter Start is " + sdf.format(fq_start.getTime()));
    System.out.println("Quarter End is " + sdf.format(fq_end.getTime()));
}
```

For people coming to this question using Java 8, you can use `LocalDate`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // Dates are DD/MM/YYYY
    String date_string = "26/06/2017";

    String quarter_start_string = "01/04/2017";

    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate ld_in = LocalDate.parse(date_string, f);

    LocalDate ld_qstart = LocalDate.parse(quarter_start_string, f);

    LocalDate fq_start = ld_qstart; 
    LocalDate fq_end = ld_qstart.plusMonths(3);
    boolean found = false; 
    int quarter = 1; 
    while (!found) { 
        if (ld_in.hashCode() >= fq_start.hashCode() && 
                ld_in.hashCode() <= fq_end.hashCode()) {
            break; 
        }
        fq_start = fq_start.plusMonths(3); 
        fq_end = fq_start.plusMonths(3);
        quarter++; 
    }

    System.out.println("Quarter# is " + quarter);
    System.out.println("Quarter Start is " + fq_start);
    System.out.println("Quarter End is " + fq_end);
}
```

Comment: So if the financial year is not 1 April, just change the first mention of the magic number "3" (but not the other two mentions) to another number? Ideally this should be a method argument.

Comment: No - magic number 3 is the length of a quarter (3 months).  If the financial year doesn't start 1 Apr, simply change quarter_start_string.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that one.

Comment: Your point is well taken though - "3" should be "MONTHS_IN_QUARTER" or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Use a calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
```

Quarter:

```
int q = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)%3;
System.out.println("Quarter: Q" + (q + 1));
```

Begining of quarter:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3*q);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Date start = cal.getTime();
System.out.println("Start: " + start);
```

End of quarter:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
Date end = cal.getTime();
System.out.println("End: " + end);
```

Comment: These troublesome old legacy date-time classes were supplanted by the java.time classes in Java 8 and later.

Comment: @BasilBourque if you don't like the `Calendar` class, write your own answer

Comment: Maurice Perry, I think that [I wrote that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63416901/5772882)