# Java : How to get quarter year based on given date

Tags: java

I am using java 8. I need to write a java code to display the Quarter based on given date. But the Q1 is from April 1st to June 30th.

```
Given Date :- between 2020/01/01 and 2020/03/31 --> Q42019
              between 2020/04/01 and 2020/06/30  --> Q12020
              between 2020/07/01 and 2020/09/30  --> Q22020
              between 2020/10/01 and 2020/12/31   --> Q32020
              between 2021/01/01 and 2021/03/31  --> Q42020
```

Comment: Have you tried something? If so, post it here.

Comment: You would probably want to count the number of days between the dates, divide it by four, than add that to the first date. This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: Di you want the numbers (4 and 2019 for Q42019) or do you want the string `Q42019`? Both are easy enough when you know how.

Comment: I wrote a new and modern answer to the linked original question for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63416901/5772882).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function can solve your problem

```
public String getQuarter(int month, int year) {
    String quarterCode = "";

    if(month >=1 && month <= 3) {
        quarterCode = "Q4";
        year = year - 1;
    }
    else if(month >=4 && month <= 6) {
        quarterCode = "Q1";
    }
    else if(month >=7 && month <= 9) {
        quarterCode = "Q2";
    }
    else if(month >=10 && month <= 12) {
        quarterCode = "Q3";
    }
    return quarterCode + year;
}
```

Comment: really nice answer, but using switch expressions might be good chice as well. they have really cool syntax. (edit: but they are not available in java8, sorry)

Answer (score 3):

Create an instance of `YearMonth`, and subtract 3 months:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(year, month).subtractMonths(3);
```

Then the quarter number is obtained by arithmetic:

```
int q = (ym.getMonthValue() - 1) / 3 + 1;
```

Then just access the fields:

```
String s = "Q" + q + ym.getYear();
```

Comment: I’d prefer something like `ym.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("QQQuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))` and save the arithmetic.